# Is it possible to examine the inner statements of a function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, statements

Working from the command line I wrote a function called `go()`. When called it receives input asking the user for a directory address in the format `drive:\directory`. No need for extra slashes or quotes or `r` literal qualifiers or what have you. Once you've provided a directory, it lists all the non-hidden files and directories under it.

I want to update the function now with a statement that stores this location in a variable, so that I can start browsing my hierarchy without specifying the full address every time.

Unfortunately I don't remember what statements I put in the function in the first place to make it work as it does. I know it's simple and I could just look it up and rebuild it from scratch with not too much effort, but that isn't the point.

As someone who is trying to learn the language, I try to stay at the command line as much as possible, only visiting the browser when I need to learn something NEW. Having to refer to obscure findings attached to vaguely related questions to rediscover how to do things I've already done is  very cumbersome.

So my question is, can I see the contents of functions I have written, and how?

Comment: uh, if it's code you've written, presumably you've got a file with that code, and you just open it in an editor... if you're defining it directly in a shell, then don't... if you want to fiddle with the code, just write it into a file and execute that file instead.

Comment: I write in the command line because executing from a file causes the shell to close immediately after it's finished executing. I know I could ask it to wait for a response so that I can analyze any output, but right now I don' have output I care to analyze. What's important is that I am able to have live interaction with my script environment from within the command line by calling functions and declaring statements and the like. IDLE isn't an option for me. I'm working from a government computer and I'm not allowed to change the firewall settings which interfere with the IDLE sub-processes.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 Or you could open a terminal/cmd and write `python /path/to/file.py` and it won't exit terminal ;)

Comment: @Mr.E `python can't open file '/users/tyler.toole/onedrive/old google drive/code/python/browse.py': [Erno 2} No suck file or directory` ---for the record I used cmd prompt. Pthon gives me an error at `google drive^/`

Comment: @Musixauce3000 Well, the error is pretty much straightforward, python couldn't find the file. You must have entered a wrong path, both windows and linux support the use of tab key to autocomplete paths, you should use it to prevent this kind of errors. Also in windows you must use double quotes for paths, at least in mine doesn't work with single quotes

Comment: @Mr.E Okay so now it's running the file but it returns to cmd mode when its finished. So I'm still not able to interact with it. From python I've tried `import`, `exec`, `execfile`, and `open().read()`

Comment: Got it. I'm using python 3.5. `>>> exec(open(r'directory\filename.py').read())`

Comment: Or you could do `python -i /path/to/file.py` (note the slight difference of the `-i` argument compared to Mr.E's answer) to run the script in interactive mode. This will run the script and you will still be in the python interpreter with access to what you wrote.

Comment: @NathanFD Thank you. I prefer this method to the lengthy `exec(open(r'd\f.e').read())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Python does not have this level of introspection. Best you can do is see the compiled byte code.

The `inspect` module details what information is available at runtime: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html

Comment: Well that's a straight forward solid answer. But I'm going to hold out a little bit for hope :(